# Python Request Post does not respond properly in a Korean Website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** some data from a Korean website for goods.

The website displays general data such as arrival date, department date, mother ship name of cargo ships.

[Website Link](http://info.bptc.co.kr:9084/content/sw/frame/berth_status_text_frame_sw_kr.jsp)

[The black button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBM8u.png) on the right is the search button.

In order to obtain data from it, some radio buttons have to be set up then hit search.

So what I thought was I could do a Post request to the website so I can extract data from the response.

Unfortunately, the response was just a plain page without the Post request.

This is the Post request

```
POST /Berth_status_text_servlet_sw_kr HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Referer: http://info.bptc.co.kr:9084/content/sw/frame/berth_status_text_frame_sw_kr.jsp
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,ko;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 40
Host: info.bptc.co.kr:9084
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close

v_time=month&ROCD=ALL&ORDER=item2&v_gu=S
```

And this is what I did in Python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

params ={'v_time': 'month',
         'ROCD': 'ALL',
         'ORDER': 'item2',
         'v_gu': 'S'}
    

response = requests.post(url, data = params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html")

print(soup)
```

I did try to put encoding and other things in the headers like below

```
response = requests.post(url, data = params, 
                         headers={'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*',
                             'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko', 
                                  'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; text/html; charset=euc-kr',
                                  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.7,ko;q=0.3'
                                 })
```

It did not work either.

The codes work fine on the other websites, so I guess it is something related to Korean characteristic.

I tried to search solutions for the issue, but I didn't have a luck.

Would you mind help me?

Thanks !

Comment: What is the final data you want to get?

Comment: @hurlenko a page with data. If you click the website, you will see the empty page besides search options. Once you press the black button, data pops up. That is what I want.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. The response returns html and you need to parse it into a more usable format. The following code converts the table from the html response into a list if dicts:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

params = {"v_time": "month", "ROCD": "ALL", "ORDER": "item2", "v_gu": "S"}


response = requests.post(
    "http://info.bptc.co.kr:9084/Berth_status_text_servlet_sw_kr", data=params
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="html.parser")
keys = [th.get_text(strip=True) for th in soup("th")]
data = [
    {key: value.get_text(strip=True) for key, value in zip(keys, row("td"))}
    for row in soup("tr")
]
print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "S/H": "0",
        "모선항차": "DPYT-21",
        "반입 마감일시": "",
        "선박명": "PEGASUS YOTTA",
        "선사": "DYS",
        "선석": "2",
        "선적": "0",
        "양하": "0",
        "입항 예정일시": "2020/06/08 21:00",
        "입항일시": "",
        "전배": "",
        "접안": "P",
        "출항 예정일시": "2020/06/09 11:00",
        "출항일시": "",
        "항로": "NCK",
    }
    ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there is a more stable way to parse!